# How to get the index of row

Tags: android

```
Image[i] = new ImageView(this);
Image[i].setImageResource(R.drawable.book);
Image[i].setPadding(200, 22, 0, 0);
Image[i].setOnClickListener(one);
```

1.I have a button in array and i set `onclicklistener` for that button . dont know how to get index of row when click
     2.im confused to how to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set id to Images like , `view.setId(i);` and using `getId()` you can get index...

```
public void onClick(View view){
  int index = view.getId();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are not setting your index values as view's ID, then you may call `Image[i].setTag(i)` to set index value and in your **onClick** method call `int index = (Integer) view.getTag()` to obtain the value.

Answer (score 0):

r u using listView? if yes then in getview() method, set the tag as

```
image.setTag(position);
```

Then  in onclick event u can do like this::

```
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
    switch(v.getTag()){
    case R.id.image:
       // do your work
    break;
    default:

  }
}
```

chk it..